# Did anybody come across a computational problem which is related to the notion of cartesian product and is at least NP-hard?

Tags: computational-complexity, co.combinatorics, algorithms

Did anybody come across a computational problem which is related to the notion of cartesian product and is at least NP-hard?

Equally interesting would be to learn about such problems with a non-trivial proof of polytime complexity. Is there anything well-known besides the graph factoring problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "related to the notion of Cartesian product"? 

Comment: Either the operation of cartesian product on some structures is explicitly present in the formulation of the problem, or the complexity proof mentions this operation.

Comment: Are you o.k. with cartesian products of posets? Perhaps the problem of deciding whether a finite poset is a nontrivial cartesian product in NP-hard. 

Comment: That seems like an incredibly broad requirement. Any time you work with a function that takes at least two inputs, you could say you're working with Cartesian products. What do you actually want to know? 

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: This is important to realize, thanks for this remark. I'd like to learn about problems like the one mentioned by Richard (see above).

Comment: @Richard: Which order on the Cartesian product is meant in this problem? This one: (x,y)≤(a,b) iff x≤a and y≤b ? Do you have in mind a candidate NP-hard problem for reduction?